# How to display a fraction as a mixed number in maxima?

Tags: maxima

I'm giving a course where students are used to the mixed number notation. However, all the calculations that maxima does, use the more traditional notation of fractions. Is it possible to present `3/2` as `1 1/2`. I need this for the latex output only.

```
(%i4) tex(3/2);
$${{3}\over{2}}$$
(%o4)                                false
```

So instead of this I would like to get:

```
(%i4) tex(3/2);
$$1 {{1}\over{2}}$$
(%o4)                                false
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign TeX properties via `texput`. Rational numbers are represented as `((RAT) mmm nnn)` which you can see via `:lisp $x` where `x` is a Maxima variable which is a rational number. So, you can set the TeX property by:

```
texput (?rat, texrat);
```

where your function `texrat` is defined as (for example):

```
texrat(x) := block ([i, r], 
                    i:floor(x), 
                    r:x-i, 
                    sconcat ("{", i, "} {{", num(r), "}\\over{", denom(r), "}}"));
```

Example:

```
(%i11) tex(sin(12/7));
$$\sin \left({1} {{5}\over{7}}\right)$$
```

Note that the new function is applied to a rational even when it's inside another operator.

Of course you can change the output of `texrat` to make it whatever you want.

Note that the `?` before `rat` is necessary in the call to `texput`.

Some of this stuff is undocumented; sorry about that.

Comment: Even nicer. I note that over here I get `((RAT SIMP) nnn mmm)`, but the rest is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is an option for this, but it's easy to make your own function.

For example:

```
texixed(a):= tex(printf(false, "~a ~a", a-mod(a,1) , mod(a,1)));
texixed(5/3);
   $$\mbox{{}1 2/3{}}$$
texixed(7/2);
   $$\mbox{{}3 1/2{}}$$
```

Comment: Nice. Tested, it works. But my output is `$$\mbox{ 1 2/3 }$$` though (without the `{}`s)

Comment: +1 I needed that without TeX output. I just took the `tex(...)` function away, so that `mixed(a) := printf(false, "~a ~a", a-mod(a,1) , mod(a,1));`. It worked smooth; for example, `mixed(5/3);`