# How to set tex1 output for all types of fractions in wxMaxima?

Tags: latex, maxima, wxmaxima

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915359/how-to-display-a-fraction-as-a-mixed-number-in-maxima) asked about setting the output of `tex1` for a numerical fraction (i.e. `x` where `ratnump(x) = true`); however, this does not seem to cover all objects that are printed as a fraction, e.g. `1/x` or `diff(ln(x),x))`.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45924465/5986783), I tried using `:lisp $x` to query the lisp form, and I get `((MEXPT SIMP) $X -1)` for `1/x` and `((%DERIVATIVE SIMP) (($LN SIMP) $X) $X 1)` for `diff(ln(x),x)`; however, I have no idea how to use this info with `texput` to specify the desired formatting.

Although I don't think it is necessarily relevant to the question, I wanted to call on a different LaTeX function, instead of `\frac` (e.g. `\tfrac`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long story, but it turns out the operator to be displayed is MQUOTIENT. Try this:

```
texput (?mquotient, lambda([e], printf (false, "\\tfrac{~a}{~a}", tex1(num(e)), tex1(denom(e)))));
```

Then I get:

```
(%i12) tex1(1/x);
(%o12)                    \tfrac{1}{x}
(%i13) tex1(y/x);
(%o13)                    \tfrac{y}{x}
(%i14) tex1((1+a/b)/(1-c/d));
(%o14)       \tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}+1}{1-\tfrac{c}{d}}
```

PS. `ln` isn't recognized by Maxima (unless you created a function named `ln`). The logarithm to the base e is `log`. Also `log10` isn't recognized (again, unless you created such a function).

Comment: Thank you Robert! Not sure why, but my version of wxMax seems to handle ln(x) as expected. I guess I must’ve loaded a package without realizing it, but it would have to have been added in such a way that permanently added the definition, as I didn’t load anything at all when I ran these commands in a new session.

Comment: About `ln`, maybe that's something that's added by wxMaxima. Ordinary Maxima doesn't know about it.